Proving simple theorems in Lean, question about working with quantifiers
Im learning in school about first order logic, and I am trying to wrap my head around some stuff.
Currently I am trying to the following:
theorem someproof : ((∃ (x : A), P x) → ∀ (x : A), Q x) → ∀ (y : A), P y → Q y :=
It makes sense in my head, if for some x, you have P x, which always implies that you have Q x, then having P x does imply Q x. The problem is I have no clue as how to proof this in lean!
so far I have this:
variables (A : Type) (P Q : A → Prop)

theorem someproof : ((∃ (x : A), P x) → ∀ (x : A), Q x) → ∀ (y : A), P y → Q y :=

assume h1 : ∃ (x : A), P x,
assume h2 : ∀ (x : A), Q x,
assume h3 : ∀ (y : A), P y,
 
-- assume hneg : ¬ ∀ (y : A), Q y, -- go for contradiction or something?

exists.elim h1 (assume z (hz : P z),
    sorry
)

I'm really fighting with lean & fol here though, I can see that the statement is provable but I have no clue how to express it in lean.

This question is perhaps better suited for https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com?

I'm not familiar with Lean, but in Coq which uses similar ideas at least behind the scenes, the final proof term would be something like fun (H1 : (exists x : A, P x) -> forall x : A, Q x) (y : A) (H2 : P y) => H1 (ex_intro P y H2) y.  So, the idea would be to introduce the hypotheses, then apply the first hypothesis using an existential introduction.
